# Why I got error This driver does not support retrieving URLs with cloudinary-laravel?

Tags: laravel, cloudinary

In laravel 8 app I need to upload images from local storage into cloudinary ( with cloudinary-laravel 1.0)
with code like :

```
Storage::disk('cloudinary')->put('cl_filename.ext', Storage::disk('local')->get('local_filename.ext'));
```

But I got error:

```
This driver does not support retrieving URLs.
```

having in env file:

```
CLOUDINARY_URL="cloudinary://XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXX@cloudinaryname"
CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET=ml_default
CLOUDINARY_NOTIFICATION_URL=
CLOUDINARY_ROOT_DIRECTORY=TAdsMedia

CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXX
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
CLOUDINARY_API_NAME=cloudinaryname
```

When I use cloudinary methods like storeOnCloudinaryAs, it works ok for me, but not storage methods.
In config/filesystems.php I added lines :

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],


    'cloudinary' => [// NOT SURE ARE THESE PARAMS VALID ?
        'driver'     => 'cloudinary',
        'api_key'        => env('CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'),
        'api_secret'     => env('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'),
        'cloud_name'     => env('CLOUDINARY_API_NAME'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],

],
```

But clearing cache I have the same error anyway...

Is something wrong with my configurations and how can it be fixed?

```
composer.json :
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^8.1",
        "arcanedev/no-captcha": "^12.2",
        "cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel": "^1.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0",
        "diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^6.1",
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/fortify": "^1.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/geotools": "@stable",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": "^2.0",
        "menarasolutions/geographer": "^0.3.10",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.3",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
        "monarobase/country-list": "^3.2",
        "pragmarx/countries": "^0.7.2",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.40",
        "spatie/emoji": "^2.2",
        "spatie/geocoder": "^3.10",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^4.0",
        "stidges/laravel-country-flags": "^2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.75",
        "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^4.4",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss": "^4.3",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

How this error can be fixed?

**MODIFIED 1:**
I suppose
Firstly I need to install carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary and next
xiaomlove/laravel-filesystem-cloudinary, but I got error installing :

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary v2.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.3
    - Installation request for laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss ^4.3 -> satisfiable by laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[4.3.0, 4.3.1].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^8.51.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v8.51.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary v2.0.0
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss 4.3.0 requires laravel/framework ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v8.51.0].
    - laravel/framework v8.51.0 requires league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.x-dev].
    - laravel/framework 8.x-dev requires league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.x-dev].
    - carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary 2.0.0-alpha requires league/flysystem 2.x-dev -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary ^2.0 -> satisfiable by carlosocarvalho/flysystem-cloudinary[2.0.0-alpha, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2].
```

I tried to install League\Flysystem first :

But failed. Please any hints how it can be

```
composer require league/flysystem :^2.2.0
...
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for league/flysystem ^2.2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.2.0, 2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss ^4.3.1 -> satisfiable by laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[4.3.1].
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss 4.3.1 requires laravel/framework ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v8.51.0].
    - laravel/framework 8.x-dev requires league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.x-dev].
    - laravel/framework v8.51.0 requires league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.x-dev
```

I tried to modify composer.json to fix these errors , like :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^8.1",
        "arcanedev/no-captcha": "^12.2",
        "cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel": "^1.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0",
        "diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^6.1",
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.1.1",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/fortify": "^1.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.51.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "league/geotools": "@stable",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": "^2.0",
        "menarasolutions/geographer": "^0.3.10",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.3",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
        "monarobase/country-list": "^3.2",
        "pragmarx/countries": "^0.7.2",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.40",
        "spatie/emoji": "^2.2",
        "spatie/geocoder": "^3.10",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^4.0",
        "stidges/laravel-country-flags": "^2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.75",
        "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^4.4",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss": "^4.3.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any hints how can it be fixed?

**MODIFIED 2:**
As I failed to install laravel-filesystem-cloudinary
I still try to use code like :

```
Storage::disk('cloudinary')->put('cl_filename.ext', Storage::disk('local')->get('local_filename.ext'));
```

But as I got error
This driver does not support retrieving URLs.

I try to debug source code and in file and opened file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php:

and debugging url method, like :

```
public function url($path)
{
    \Log::info(  varDump($path, ' -1 url  $path::') );
    $adapter = $this->driver->getAdapter();
    \Log::info(  varDump($adapter, ' -1 url  $adapter::') );

    if ($adapter instanceof CachedAdapter) {
        $adapter = $adapter->getAdapter();
        \Log::info(  varDump($adapter, ' -2 INSIDE url  $adapter::') );
    }

    if (method_exists($adapter, 'getUrl')) {
        return $adapter->getUrl($path);
    } elseif (method_exists($this->driver, 'getUrl')) {
        return $this->driver->getUrl($path);
    } elseif ($adapter instanceof AwsS3Adapter) {
        return $this->getAwsUrl($adapter, $path);
    } elseif ($adapter instanceof Ftp || $adapter instanceof Sftp) {
        return $this->getFtpUrl($path);
    } elseif ($adapter instanceof LocalAdapter) {
        return $this->getLocalUrl($path);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException('This driver does not support retrieving URLs.');
    }
}
```

I see output

```
[2021-07-28 09:18:01] local.INFO: NULL : -1 url  $path:: : NULL
[2021-07-28 09:18:01] local.INFO:  (Object of CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\CloudinaryAdapter) : -1 url  $adapter:: : Array
(
   [cloudinary] => Cloudinary\Cloudinary Object
        (
            [configuration] => Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration Object
                (
                    [sections:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => cloud
                            [1] => api
                            [2] => url
                            [3] => tag
                            [4] => responsive_breakpoints
                            [5] => auth_token
                            [6] => logging
                        )

                    [includeSensitive:protected] => 1
                    [cloud] => Cloudinary\Configuration\CloudConfig Object
                        (
                            [cloudName] => NNNNNNNNNNN
                            [apiKey] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [apiSecret] => WWWWWWWWWWWW
                            [oauthToken] =>
                            [explicitlySetKeys:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [cloudName] => 1
                                    [apiKey] => 1
                                    [apiSecret] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [api] => Cloudinary\Configuration\ApiConfig Object
                        (
                            [uploadPrefix:protected] =>
                            [apiProxy] =>
                            [connectionTimeout] =>
                            [timeout:protected] =>
                            [uploadTimeout:protected] =>
                            [chunkSize:protected] =>
                            [callbackUrl] =>
                            [explicitlySetKeys:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
```

as for Cloudinary Adapter method url not found and I can not manually edit file under “vendor/”
it must be done in some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED 2

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom filesystem see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#custom-filesystems

You can create it yourself or use a existing package, after googling I found this one for example.
https://github.com/xiaomlove/laravel-filesystem-cloudinary

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED 1